# Adding a variable with missing observations to an existing pandas df without loosing observations in the larger df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, missing-data

I have two dataframes. One called ENFORE with 139 observations:

```
citation    Enfore
0170/0952   1
0175/0686   1
0184/0521   1
0183/0726   1
0178/0595   0
```

And another data frame called CITATIONS with 668 observations that also have the column citation, but not Enfore. All the citations in ENFORE are in the CITATIONS data frame.

I would like to add the column Enfore to the CITATIONS data frame and fill in observations that are not in the ENFORE data frame with an 'X'.

Using various variations of this code (merge and join)

```
enfore_merged = pd.merge(enfore , harrington_citations, on = 'citation')
```

I have not been able to create the data frame I describe above.

Comment: I have added an answer. If it doesn't work, could you show an example of CITATIONS dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
enfore_merged = harrington_citations.merge(enfore, how='left', on='citation')
enfore_merged['Enfore'] = enfore_merged['Enfore'].fillna('X')
```